# How can I make use of uniqueConstraints for multiple columns in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a task to create database, where I could be able to store information about currency bid and ask values from particular days. My entity has few fields, two of them are currencyType (enum USD, EUR and so on) and currencyDate (LocalDate). Both of them should not be unique, but their merge should be (I want to use query.uniqueResult() to get currency from database). Thats why I used:

```
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"currencyType", "currencyDate"}))
```

I though that everytime I try to add to database already existing combination of currencyType and currencyDate, the database will just ignore the query, but it gives me an error, eg:

```
ERROR: Duplicate entry '0-2017-10-27' for key 'UK56cur2s470vruol04nntdbl49'
```

where first 0 stands for currencyType(in int) and other part is date. How can I make hibernate work the way I want? I mean to pass the query, when it would duplicate the record?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You created a unique constraint wrt. the currency type and the date. Thus, it is expected that hibernate throws an exception if you try to add an entry with a combination of currency type and date that is already present in the database. What exactly is not working as expected? What do you mean by "make hibernate work the way I want"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I know to get behavior like you want is to make your combination of this two fields as `Id` and to use `merge` or `saveOrUpdate` methods for storing, but I don't think that it is good design. As for me the best way of solving this is to fetch record from db by this two values and update it if present or create new if not.